# How to make the touch sensor work in Linux kernel?

Tags: kernel, driver

**My platform:** Beagle Bone Black, Ubuntu, kernel: 3.14.29-ti-r46

**Sensor:** MPR121, connect to Beagle's i2c-2

I want to make touch sensor MPR121 (Freescal touchkey chip) work on my Beagle Bone Black. The kernel driver is ready there. But it needs to work with device tree.

First, I make a device tree dts file for MPR121 as below:

```
tomxue@ubuntu:~/Tom/Source_Code/BBB/Ubuntu/ti-linux-kernel-dev/KERNEL/arch/arm/boot/dts$ cat am335x-bone-i2c2-mpr121.dts 
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2012 Texas Instruments Incorporated - http://www.ti.com/
 *
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License version 2 as
 * published by the Free Software Foundation.
 */
/dts-v1/;

#include "am33xx.dtsi"
#include "am335x-bone-common.dtsi"
#include "am335x-bone-common-pinmux.dtsi"

/ {
        model = "TI AM335x BeagleBone Black";
        compatible = "ti,am335x-bone-black", "ti,am335x-bone", "ti,am33xx";
};

&ocp {
        /* i2c2 */
        P9_19_pinmux {
                mode = "i2c";
        };
        P9_20_pinmux {
                mode = "i2c";
        };
};

&i2c2 {
        status = "okay";
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <>; /* pinctrl-0 = <&i2c2_pins>; */

        clock-frequency = <100000>;

        touchkey: mpr121@5a {
                compatible = "fsl,mpr121";
                reg = <0x5a>;
        };
};

#include "am335x-bone-i2c2-cape-eeprom.dtsi"
```

The Makefile under `dts` directory as below:

```
dtb-$(CONFIG_ARCH_OMAP2PLUS) += omap2420-h4.dtb \
    ...
    am335x-base0033.dtb \
    am335x-bone-i2c2-mpr121.dtb \
    am3517-craneboard.dtb \
```

And then I recompile the kernel together with the device tree files. And use the official script to flash the kernel image, modules and device trees onto my Beagle Bone Black.

After reboot Beagle, I checked my new kernel version:

```
root@arm:/dev/input# uname -a
Linux arm 3.14.29-ti-r46 #2 SMP PREEMPT Tue Apr 21 14:30:14 CST 2015 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

And then insmod the module:

```
root@arm:~# insmod mpr121_touchkey.ko
```

The dmesg has nothing about mpr121.
And then I checked i2c-2, the sensor really connects to i2c-2 of Beagle at 0x5a address(same to device tree setting):

```
root@arm:~# i2cdetect -y -r 2
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- UU UU UU UU -- -- 5a -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Finally, I checked the input device like this:

```
root@arm:/dev/input# ls
mice
```

Nothing about the sensor!
What do I miss? How to make the sensor kernel driver work?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi. I know your question is about a year ago, but I have a problem with my friendlyarm. could you look at this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43221725/tiny6410-friendlyarm-connect-to-capacitive-lcd-but-touch-not-worked-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the driver source ([mpr121_touchkey.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/input/keyboard/mpr121_touchkey.c?v=3.14)) it seems to be a common input driver.

First thing to check, input drivers like this once loaded (*insmod*) **must** appear in `/proc/bus/input/devices` and `/proc/bus/input/handlers`, the device node into `/dev` depends on the *device manager* you're using (*udev* ...) it may fail to create the node, there must be a way to know the minor to create the node manually (the major could be always 13 (I'm not sure)) and read from it with something like *hexdump* to check the hw and driver are working.

If the driver appear in the `/proc` nodes mentioned above you should check the configuration of your *device manager*.

If it doesn't appear probably you need to add some *printk* in the driver's source and check *dmesg* for what is wrong (the driver show already some *dev_err* but maybe some flow isn't covered).