# tiny6410 friendlyarm connect to capacitive lcd but touch not worked in linux

Tags: linux, arm, embedded-linux

I connect my Capacitive lcd to tiny6410 and install linux on it. I also change the friendlyarm.ini to this:

```
#This line cannot be removed. by FriendlyARM(www.arm9.net)

CheckOneButton=No
Action=Install
OS= Linux

LCD-Mode = No
LCD-Type = S70

LowFormat = No
VerifyNandWrite = No
CheckCRC32=No


StatusType = Beeper| LED

#################### Linux #####################
Linux-BootLoader = Superboot-6410.bin
Linux-Kernel = Linux/zImage
Linux-CommandLine = root=/dev/mtdblock2 rootfstype=yaffs2 init=/linuxrc console=ttySAC0,115200 skipcali=yes ctp=2
Linux-RootFs-InstallImage = Linux/rootfs_qtopia_qt4.img
Linux-RootFs-RunImage = Linux/rootfs_qtopia_qt4.ext3
```

and play with ctp=1 (not work),ctp=2 (not work),ctp=3 (not work)
my lcd is S70(when linux is install it writes on screen lcd type is S70
(auto detect))

this device has resistive lcd at first but it was broken then I changed it
to capacitive lcd but touch not work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the answer. Do not try, tiny6410 does not support capacitive LCD touch screen.(this is factory answer)